PowerShell not recognizing path
If I run the following simple powershell command from the powershell command prompt, I get the results expected.  Although when I run that same command from a SQL Server Agent job I get an error of invalid path.
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\je\AppData\Roaming\Files\*.tmp" | Move-Item -Destination  "C:\Users\je\Documents" -Force

Ran command from powershell command prompt and SQL Server agent expecting same results

The SQL agent will not have permission to see the user folders.

Perhaps you actually want a Scheduled Task in the normal Windows Task Scheduler instead? That can run under the user's account when logged in.
